# Date, place and name in CV

Tags: letters

I am a beginner in LaTeX and I use [THIS](https://github.com/Mgccl/mgccl-school-work/blob/master/cv.tex) for creating my CV.

I need to add *date*, *place* and my *name* (signature) to the bottom of this CV document but of course when I add it to the last section, it has a formatting which I don't want to. I would like to align it to the left edge. Shortly I would like to have it and format it like a **normal** text under these section. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\vspace{2cm} % or any other length 
\hspace{-1.2in}Signature:\par
\vspace{2cm} % or any other length 
\hspace{-1.2in}Name:\dotfill \hfill \hfill
```